# Google Dart JSON Extraction

Tags: json, dart

I'm attempting to pull out data from a nested array in JSON but cannot seem to get the values correct.  Right now, all values of the nested operatingSystem array print out in the table when I only need the name of the operating system.  My code is below and please let me if you need more information.

Dart:

```dart
List<Map> assetList;

// LinkedHashMap preserves key entry order
LinkedHashMap<String, Map> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map>();
for (var d in assetList) {
  HashMap rowMap = new HashMap();

  String domainId = d["process"]["processId"];

  //first <td> element, the rest follow in succession
  dataMap[domainId] = rowMap;

  rowMap["domainId"] = domainId;

  //is still not checking if null
  if(d["asset"]["operatingSystem"].containsKey("name")){
    rowMap["operatingSystem"] = d["asset"]["operatingSystem"]["name"];
  } else{
    rowMap["operatingSystem"] = d["asset"]["operatingSystem"];
  }

  //print out table data for debugging
  print(rowMap.toString());
  print(d);
```

JSON:

```dart
 "asset":{  
    "assetId":"8a498592469189660146918d9e2f0000",
    "oplock":0,
    "domainName":"",
    "latitude":58.92,
    "ipAddress":"4.4.4.4",
    "longitude":-37.23,
    "operatingSystem":{  
       "osId":2,
       "oplock":0,
       "name":"Windows 8"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add the code that shows how you get the JSON into the `assetList`? I wonder why you call it `assetList` when it actually is a map. What is the 'operatingSystem array'? Can you please edit and improve your question. Which variable do you print? What value(s) is/are printed and what values do you actually want printed.

Comment: The operatingSystem map is in the JSON within the asset map.  I want the operatingSystem name printed not all of the operating system details.  I can successfully print everything else but that.  Please see my edits above.

Comment: It seems the answer below is correct, but its hard to verify because your code still doesn't show how you load the JSON into `assetList`.

Comment: Ok, it seems as though I need to do null checking on the operatingSystem map.

Comment: What do you mean? 'name' is not set for each asset?

Comment: Ok, well how about this, how would I check to see if the operatingSystem name is null or not? If so, I could replace it with the text, "NA".

Comment: d["asset"]["operatingSystem"].containsKey("name");

Comment: Like this?  if(d["asset"]["operatingSystem"].containsKey("name")){
      rowMap["operatingSystem"] = d["asset"]["operatingSystem"]["name"];
      }
      else{
        rowMap["operatingSystem"] = "NA";
      }

Comment: Check in my updated question.

Comment: Seems correct. Hint: you don't need `.toString()` for `print`. `print` calls `.toString()` automatically on the passed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go one level deeper. You are printing out the object's operatingSystem header but the operatingSystem header has 3 attributes.

The corect syntax is

```
json["asset"]["operatingSystem"]["name"];
```

You could also do it like this which I believe is more standard when it comes to JS and JSON

```
json.asset.operatingSystem.name
```

Comment: It worked on my computer. Log your JSON to make sure you're getting the expected object and be sure to verify you're using valid JSON (you can do this at www.jsonlint.com). Also, make sure you replace "json" in my example code with "d" in your code ;)

Comment: Ok, well how about this, how would I check to see if the operatingSystem name is null or not?  If so, I could replace it with the text, "NA".

Comment: You can just use 'if (!object)' or 'if (object == null)'